# Take A Snippet of Assembly and Make All Side Effects Explicit?

Tags: assembly, x86, ida

I came across a small function whose only side effects were to modify the state of some processor flags. When I decompiled this function using the Hex Rays decompiler, I simply got an empty function, which is not useful at all in figuring out what the function does. Instead I had to look up each instruction in the assembly language manual and read the pseudocode to determine the net effect of the function. Is there some tool I can paste assembly instructions into and it will spit out *all* side effects, including flags? I'm interested in x86.

Comment: When you say you decompiled it, you mean via Hex-Rays?

Comment: Yeah I was using IDA and Hex-Rays.

Comment: @user2142: best bet is to learn assembly first, get used to that and then proceed to the decompiler, not the other way around.

Comment: I know know assembly I just had to consult the manual because I did not have all the flag side effects memorized

Comment: @user2142: most concise most general-purpose opcodes can be found on a [two side cheat page here](http://www.jegerlehner.ch/intel/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hex-Rays performs liveness analysis and dead code elimination, which in the case of your function, it sounds like it decided everything was dead.  I think it's impossible to tell Hex-Rays via __usercall that the return location for some function is in a flag location, so under that assumption, Hex-Rays can't help in this situation.

What you want is a tool that is capable of rendering the intermediate language translation for a given instruction or block of instructions.  To that extent, tools such as BitBlaze, BAP, and miasm can help.  Also see [this link](http://edmcman.bitbucket.org/blog/2013/02/27/bap-for-everyone/) for a language-agnostic interface to BAP.

Comment: Never heard of this tool, this is exactly what I want. Though I guess I am depending on the fact that they read the Intel manuals carefully and got all the side effects right.

Comment: No matter what tool you use, you will depend on a fact such as that.  In the case of dynamic analysis, you can at least watch in the debugger to verify that changes are happening in the specified locations.

Comment: @user2142: To me it sounds a bit odd that someone would rather read an IR and not the original assembly code. May I ask why do you want that?

Comment: I'm not really sure I want that. Just asked a question that popped into my head while reversing!